# The meaning of the “for” in this sentence

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence-construction

I came across the following sentence ”students have a huge decision to make, for it is at this time that they must consider their options in regard to higher education.” What’s the meaning of the ”for it is...”? Can someone provide me with some examples of how to use it correctly?

Comment: In that use, "for" is a conjunction meaning the same as "because" or "since". The meaning is in all the dictionary entries for "for"; you just have to search for "conjunction" as the part of speech.